# Google Analytics query builder, first touch for source

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, query-builder

I'm still fairly new to Google Analytics but I want to achieve the following table using the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

```
source | # first touches | customers with source as first touch | avg customer life-cycle value
```

I have tried the following `query`

- `metrics`: ga:sessions
- `dimensions`: ga:source

But I don't really know how I can access the `first touch` data.
First touch means the first time a person visited your site. Also known as `first interaction`.

Is this even possible by just using google Analytics?

Edit: Maybe there is a way to link an `id` to the Google Analytics data?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "first touch"  The query explorer just an application.  This question really isn't programing related.

Comment: First touch means when a user visited the site for the first time. It's the opposite of last touch, when a person touched the site for the last time. @DaImTo

Comment: I think the closest thing you are going to get is the page level dimensions.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking  I think its going to be hard because you cant really track what each individual user did.

Comment: @DaImTo So the easiest thing for me to do is save the data manual in my own database? (This is what I'm talking about https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en)

Comment: My advice.  Go bug they guys on Google+ with this question.  https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537 someone there will know the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a GA expert but I think this approach would be the best.

Use custom `variables` and/or `dimensions` to link a user `id` to for an `referrer` for example.

You could also try and save it into your own `database` if it's acceptable.

This is how we solved it once at my company.

Comment: Let me know how it went!